# Pipe não encontrado - Angular 5

Tags: angular

Estou tendo um problema na criação de um Pipe personalizado.

Criei o seguinte module (pipes.module.ts):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CnpjPipe } from './cnpj.pipe';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations:   
    [
        CnpjPipe
    ],
    exports:
    [
        CnpjPipe
    ],
})
export class PipesModule { 
    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: PipesModule,
            providers: [],
        };
    }
}
```

Esse é o meu Pipe que foi criado:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'cnpj'
})
export class CnpjPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        return `${value.substr(0, 2)}.${value.substr(2, 3)}.${value.substr(5, 3)}/${value.substr(8, 4)}-${value.substr(12, 2)}`;
    }
}
```

Fiz a importação desse module no meu app.module.ts:

```
import { PipesModule } from './pipes/pipes.module';

declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...,
        PipesModule.forRoot()
    ],
```

Na hora de fazer a utilização do Pipe dessa maneira:

```
<div class="col-md-2 text-left">
    {{ objUsuario.cnpj | cnpj }}
</div>
```

Da o seguinte erro:

**

> The pipe 'cnpj' could not be found

**

Comment: Isto pode parecer estupido, mas ja tentas-te mudar _a ordem_ da array de imports? A mim acontece-me algumas vezes que X import nao fica bem feito e passo-o para uns indexes antes e o import funciona :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, aconteceu que eu estava usando o Pipe dentro de um componente dentro de um shared module.

E o meu Pipe module estava sendo chamado em um module único da aplicação.

Assim, o componente dentro do shared module não conseguia encontrar o Pipe que estava importado dentro de um modulo único.